# how to write python list in the database table

Tags: python

This is my list:

```
[['ID', '001'], ['Name', 'Jon'], ['Score', '90'], ['Semester', 'Fall']]
[['ID', '002'], ['Name', 'Ama'], ['Score', '87'], ['Semester', 'Fall']]
```

i want to write this list in to a table in sqlserver database as below:

```
ID   Name   Score   Semester
001  Jon    90      Fall
002  Ama    87      Fall
```

Can anyone help to code it in python please?

```
with open('files.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Create an empty list to store the lines
    lines = []

    # Iterate over the lines of the file
    for line in file:
        # Remove the newline character at the end of the line
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(':') 
        line = [x.strip(' ') for x in line]

        # Append the line to the list
        lines.append(line)

# Print the list of lines
print(lines)
```

Comment: Where in your code do you connect to your SQL Server database?

Comment: Why is your data formatted like thst? Why a list of `[name, value]` instead of a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string processing to parse the lines. Use the built-in `ast.literal_eval()`.

Then you can extract the values from each list, create a list of values, and use that as the argument to `cursor.executemany()`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('files.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Create an empty list to store the lines
    lines = []

    # Iterate over the lines of the file
    for line in file:
        line = literal_eval(line)
        row = [value for field, value in line]
        lines.append(row)

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO yourTable (id, name, score, semester) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", lines)
```

Replace `cursor` with the variable holding the cursor you've opened to your database.

Comment: line = literal_eval(line)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 62, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval') I AM GETTING THIS ERROR

Comment: I don't see an error message in there.

Answer (score -2):

To insert the data from your list into a SQL Server database table, you can use the **pyodbc** library in Python

```
import pyodbc

# Your list of data
data_list = [
    ['ID', '001'], ['Name', 'Jon'], ['Score', '90'], ['Semester', 'Fall'],
    ['ID', '002'], ['Name', 'Ama'], ['Score', '87'], ['Semester', 'Fall']
]

# Reshape the list into a dictionary for easier processing
data_dict = {}
for item in data_list:
    key, value = item
    if key in data_dict:
        data_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        data_dict[key] = [value]

# Establish a connection to your SQL Server database
connection = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    'SERVER=your_server_name;'
    'DATABASE=your_database_name;'
    'UID=your_username;'
    'PWD=your_password'
)

# Create a cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Prepare and execute the SQL INSERT statement
for i in range(len(data_dict['ID'])):
    sql_insert = f"INSERT INTO YourTableName (ID, Name, Score, Semester) VALUES ('{data_dict['ID'][i]}', '{data_dict['Name'][i]}', '{data_dict['Score'][i]}', '{data_dict['Semester'][i]}')"
    cursor.execute(sql_insert)

# Commit the changes and close the connection
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Not only is this open to SQL Injection but you're executing an insert in a loop, so it has terrible efficiency

Comment: @A.Deb is there anything we can avoid sql injection or make code performance efficient?

Comment: @Aftab My answer shows how to use placeholders and `executemany()` to solve those two problems.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, my list has both fieldNames and Values as given above in the question. and executemany is inserting both as values in the table. any idea? data_list = [
    ['ID', '001'], ['Name', 'Jon'], ['Score', '90'], ['Semester', 'Fall'],
    ['ID', '002'], ['Name', 'Ama'], ['Score', '87'], ['Semester', 'Fall']
]

Comment: @Aftab That's why the code in my answer extracts the values from that list, with the list comprehension.

Comment: @Aftab
Use parameterised queries instead of inserting values directly into the SQL query string. Parameterized queries automatically handle escaping and quoting of values, reducing the risk of SQL injection attacks.
Additionally consider using the executemany method to perform bulk inserts. This can be more efficient than executing individual INSERT statements in a loop.